# Can we integrate an ag-grid datagrid with a react native app

Tags: react-native, ag-grid

Is it possible to use Ag-grid datagrid inside a React Native application running on android platform?

I tried the steps similar to a react web app and I got the following kind of error in logcat,

```
  ReactNativeJS ▶︎ Invariant Violation: View config not found for name div. Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
                                 │
                                 │ This error is located at:
                                 │ in div (created by AgGridReact)
                                 │ in AgGridReact (at App.js:58)
                                 │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
                                 │ in View (at App.js:57)
                                 │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
                                 │ in View (at App.js:53)
                                 │ in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
                                 │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
                                 │ in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
                                 │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
                                 │ in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
                                 └ in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: No, you cant AGGrid is JS based framework, React Native need to compile into native Android/iOS code

Comment: If someone from ag-grid sees this: It would be amazing if you supported react native. Build your app once, deploy to Linux/Mac/Windows with Electron, deploy to web AND use the same code for react native on phones, with excellent performance. I'd gladly pay an additional deployment license for that.

Answer (score 1):

ag-grid scales quite well to small screens. You wouldn't get as good an experience that Excel or Google Sheets provide with their native applications, but if it doesn't have to be perfect, you can render the grid in a WebView: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview